# Why does HP update suggest to install 100-series update on 360-series server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hp, hp-proliant

While running HP update on my HP DL360p server i have noticed that one of the suggested items is for 100-series server. Why so? It also marked as "critical to install" so I've decided to answer here. Am I really should install 100-series update on 360-series server?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You should not.

HP ProLiant Service Pack/Support Pack installers routinely ask for more packages to install than necessary. These preselections are called "Bundles". On the Linux side, I [create my own bundles](http://communitylinux.org/node/265) where I strip out driver support for hardware and devices not installed in my target system. You should do the same.

Deselect the ProLiant 100-series drivers because you clearly don't have an 100-series system.